# MongoDB - No autodiscovery for clustering

Tags: mongodb, replication

*Scenario:*

1. I install MongoDB v3.6 on **3** MongoDB nodes
2. Set a keyfile on the 3 nodes
3. Name a Replset in the `mongod.conf`
4. Restart MongoDB

At this point MongoDB automatically initiates the replica set among the 3 nodes. This is undesired in my situation.

*Question*:
How can I ensure MongoDB doesn't automatically initiates a ReplSet?

I want to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my solution was to:

1. Install mongoDB
2. Place config without security/keyfile enabled in the config -> restart mongo
3. Create users
4. Initiate replica set
5. Place config with security/keyfile enabled in the config - > restart mongo

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to manually initiate a replica set. Can you elaborate a bit on your use case? To my knowledge, In MongoDB replica sets, the secondaries follow the operation log (oplog) of an upstream host which can either be the primary or a secondary with a newer oplog. This assures the high availability of the setup and all this happens in the background with auto discovery. Why do you want to fiddle with the Auto-discovery and initiating the replica sets? May be I can learn from your use case if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Because I use Ansible to initiate and manage the cluster. I also want the run to be idempotent. 
I need to manage replication and authentication. But if has a replication setting in it's config, then authentication cannot be managed anymore.
So, when MongoDB automatically clusters for the first time, then I / Ansible have no control anymore over the authentication.